# Whitelisting a web resource using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

The standard method to secure a web application is to forbid unauthenticated access to everything and white-list specific resources.

All of the following XML fragments allow access to a resource, with different though implications:

```
<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" filters="none" />

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/> 

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Which should be used when and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

```
<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />
```

will bypass the security filters completely, which is usually what you want to do with the kind of resource we're dealing with here (i.e. favicon.ico).

If you do

```
<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

you will still be able to get information regarding the currently logged in user (if any) when rendering the resource (might be useful when rendering a page that should be accessible without login but you still want to be able to present e.g. the user name on the rendered page if the user is logged in).

`permitAll` is the same thing, but with EL syntax.

`ROLE_ANONYMOUS` appears to grant access to anonymous users, but deny anthenticated ones.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" filters="none" />
```

is old syntax, to my knowledge it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check out below use cases for each of you mentioned.

*<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />*
**This filter chain you can used in login pages to remove from security.**

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" filters="none" />
**First of all this intercept url is incompatible from the 3.1 version of spring security. if you are using version lower than 3.1 than you can use for same purpose of** *<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />*.

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
**This intercept url you can used in case if require to give permit all your user who has authentication access.**

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
**This allows you to access pattern for ROLE_ANONYMOUS only.**

<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />